# Read string in Objective-C console application?

Tags: objective-c, string, input, console-application

What is the best way to read string input from a simple Objective-C console application?

I would just like to store the input as an NSString variable.

I've seen multiple people post about `scanf`, `gets` and others, but they everyone seems to say that they're "unreliable", or "open to attack".

I can see how this could be true for `gets` but I'm looking for the best possible way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

scanf should be mostly secure as long as you use your input correctly.

I've heard of scanf_s which is supposed to be more secure but work the same way.